# Apache Camel: How to send two http requests in parallel and wait for the responses?

Tags: java, apache-camel

In Apache Camel, where I am defining a route, how can I send two or more http requests in parallel and wait on their 'futures'to get the responses for further processing like in Java with AsyncHttpClient?

```
AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new DefaultAsyncHttpClient();
Future<Response> f = asyncHttpClient.prepareGet("http://www.example.com/").execute();
Response r = f.get();
```

Just for the context, the following route calls the GET contacts http call and returns the response synchronously.

```
from("direct:getContact")
.to("http://host:port/contacts/1453")
```

Comment: I believe you are looking for information on the Camel Async library: http://camel.apache.org/async.html

Comment: Thanks Matthew,
I was trying out the Async API with the ProducerTemplate and face some difficulty. Could you please take a look and see if I am doing it right?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409460/apache-camel-producertemplate-not-unmarshalling-the-response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to split You route into many smaller routes. Then You can perform necessary unmarshalling there.

See [question about unmarshalling http response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37410261/3545122)

```
from("direct:getContact")
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            CamelContext context = exchange.getContext();
            ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = context.createProducerTemplate();

            // Asynchronous call to internal route
            Future<Contact> contact = 
                producerTemplate.asyncRequestBody("direct:invokeSomeRestApi", null, Contact.class);  

            // Do rest of the work
            exchange.getOut().setBody(contact.get());
        }
    });

// Unmarshalling REST response
JacksonDataFormat jacksonDataFormat = new JacksonDataFormat();
jacksonDataFormat.setUnmarshalType(Contact.class);

// Internal route definition
from("direct:invokeSomeRestApi")
    .to("http://localhost:8080/api/contact/2345")
    .unmarshal(jacksonDataFormat);
```

Comment: Thanks Rafal! Spot on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use camel **multicast** with **parallelProcessing** and **aggregationStrategy**

This example:

```
  .multicast()
     .executorService(executorService)
     .parallelProcessing()
     .stopOnException()
     .aggregationStrategy(new SearchDocumentAggregator())
     .to(direct(EXEC_DOCUMENT_FULLTEXT_SEARCH))
     .to(direct(EXEC_SEARCH_DOCUMENT_METADATA))
 .end()
```

perform the fulltext-search and metadata-search in parallel and the **SearchDocumentAggregator** aggregate (sum) the results

public class **SearchDocumentAggregator** implements AggregationStrategy {
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange original, Exchange resource) {

```
    if(newExchange.getIn().getHeader(ServiceUtils.RESPONSE_FROM, String.class).equals(EnumDppResponseFrom.SEARCH_FULLTEXT.name())) {
       //here get the fulltext response to SearchAggregator
    }
    if(newExchange.getIn().getHeader(ServiceUtils.RESPONSE_FROM, String.class).equals(EnumDppResponseFrom.SEARCH_METADATA.name())) {
         //here get the metadata response and add to SearchAggregator
    }

    newExchange.getIn().setBody(fullTextSearchAggregator, SearchAggregator.class);


     return newExchange;
}
```

}