# Apache Camel: ProducerTemplate not unmarshalling the response

Tags: java, apache-camel

Camel version: 2.15.6

I used the ProducerTemplate to send a http request and get the response like this.

```
from("direct:getContact")
.process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        CamelContext context = exchange.getContext();
                        ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = context.createProducerTemplate();
Contact contact = producerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders( 
                                "http://localhost:8080/api/contact/2345", 
                                null, headers, Contact.class); 

logger.info("Contact is: " + new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(contact)); 

exchange.getOut().setBody(contact);

});
```

I get the contact as null.

When I try to get it as Object like this:

```
Object contact = producerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders( 
                                "http://localhost:8080/api/contact/2345", 
                                null, headers); 


logger.info("Contact is: " + new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(contact));
```

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer
>   found for class
>   org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream$WrappedInputStream
>   and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid
>   exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEA

NS) )

Why is ProducerTemplate not able to unmarshall the response to the specified object? 
How can this be achieved?

**Edit**

The Fix I observed is as follows:
If I first get the output as string and then deserialize it, it works.

```
String responseString = producerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders( 
                                    "http://localhost:8080/api/contact/2345", 
                                    null, headers, String.class); 

Contact contact = new ObjectMapper().readValue(responseString, Contact.class);
```

Comment: Are You requesting to Your own Camel route?

Comment: I am requesting to a Contact service REST API which is another service hosted on the same machine.

Comment: And how are You creating `producerTemplate`? Using CamelContext without any Routes?

Comment: Oh, okay. I've only added a small snippet. Please see the updated question. I've added the complete route. I am using the ProducerTemplate inside the Processor, in which I want to do additional things with the returned contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Answer is more of an combination of Rafal's to show how you can tie his code back into your solution to get the desired result.  Thanks Rafal for setting up the sub route in this sample.

Assumptions: You have the rest API up and available already

Your new Code:

```
from("direct:getContact")
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            CamelContext context = exchange.getContext();
            ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = context.createProducerTemplate();
            //Call another route not the rest endpoint
            Future<Contact> contact = producerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders( 
                "direct:RetrieveContactRoute", 
                 null, headers, Contact.class); 

             logger.info("Contact is: " + new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(contact.get())); 

             //Set the In Body not the Out Body 
             exchange.getIn().setBody(contact.get());
    });
```

A separate Route

```
JacksonDataFormat jacksonDataFormat = new JacksonDataFormat();
jacksonDataFormat.setUnmarshalType(Contact.class);

from("direct:RetrieveContactRoute")
    .to("http://localhost:8080/api/contact/2345")
    .unmarshal(jacksonDataFormat);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create Your route like this:

```
//org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat

JacksonDataFormat jacksonDataFormat = new JacksonDataFormat();
jacksonDataFormat.setUnmarshalType(Contact.class);

from("direct:getContact")
    .to("http://localhost:8080/api/contact/2345")
    .unmarshal(jacksonDataFormat);
```

After unmarshalling You should have `Contant` object in body.

Dependency is from:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks Rafal. This works fine. But, as I said, I want to do some more work in the Processor.

What I have in mind is to request multiple REST APIs in parallel and create a Bulk response which I can return from the route.

For example, get the contact info, get the events attended by the contact, get his address etc.

I was looking at the ProducerTemplate.asyncRequestBody API which will return a Future object. I was thinking of using this to issue requests in parallel and wait on the future objects. But, I am stuck on the unmarshalling issue.

Comment: You should do it in route. Use some asynchronous components for this. Then You can still use `unmarshal` method.

Comment: ProducerTemplate.asyncRequestBody API is the only async API I could find which suits my needs closely. I've also ased the question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37388376/apache-camel-how-to-send-two-http-requests-in-parallel-and-wait-for-the-respons?noredirect=1#comment62292518_37388376 


Do you have any alternatives in mind? I found the 'Splitter and Aggregator' like patterns an overkill for my use case.